# How to Monitor places swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, cllocationmanager

i work on app where i monitor places and send local notification when enter region.

i save these places in realm database and check for region.

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    print("Updated user's location")
    shouldSetRegion = false
    updateLocation()
    print((locations.last?.coordinate.longitude)!)

    if !(realm.objects(Coupon.self).isEmpty) {
        for item in realm.objects(Coupon.self) {

            let lat: CLLocationDegrees = CLLocationDegrees(item["lat"] as! String)!
            let lng: CLLocationDegrees = CLLocationDegrees(item["lng"] as! String)!

            center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat, longitude: lng)
            region = CLCircularRegion(center: center, radius: 5000, identifier: "startPosition")
            print(region)
            manager.startMonitoring(for: region)
        }
        manager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
}
```

i use this code and he only get notification when user enter last region on database although the database contains more than one place.

```
func updateLocation(){
    shouldSetRegion = true
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}
```

so any help about monitoring places and send local notification.

```
@objc func didEnterRegion() {

    print("da5alt hena")

    for item in realm.objects(Coupon.self){
        let title = item["name"] as! String
        let body = item["desc"] as! String
        let id = item["BranchId"] as! String
        VKNotificationService.sharedInstance.locationRequest(title, body, for: id)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use a unique `identifier` for each region that you want to monitor. Since you are using a constant `identifier` each region replaces the previous one and you are left only monitoring the final region.

I suggest you use the item `name` as the region `identifier`